# Exception Unable to set property 'href' of undefined or null reference when

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is this: I try to dynamically change the innerHTML and href of an LINk in a function `CheckCookie` which is executed in body - onload. Here is the function:

```
function checkCookie()
{
    var username = getCookie("username");

    if (username != null && username != "")
    {       
        document.getElementById("firstlink").href = "http://localhost:8080/newLogIN/probalassfinalwithoutstyle.html";
        document.getElementById("firstlink").innerHTML = "Go to my lesson";       
    }
}
```

also I have another jquery function which is executed on document ready

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
}


$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

In my body I've got this

```
<body onload="CheckCookie()">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3">LoGG
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#" id="firstlink">Gismo Account</a> </li>

    </div>
</body>
```

Everything works as I want but when I add

```
document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "Hi," + getCookie("username");
```

to change the InnerHtML of dd div it gives me an exception

SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'href' of undefined or null reference

Comment: When do you execute that code?

Comment: Why are you mixing different style of event handling (body onload vs. jQuery ready)? That can easily lead to problems - trigger your first script the same way.

Comment: Since you replace the contents of dd you don't have the "firstlink" anymore - this is causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "Hi," + getCookie("username");` you are replacing the content of the `dd` element entirely. This includes the `firstlink` anchor. Thus when you come to change that link there is no element with that ID and thus it fails with that error.